# Replace all in javascript for one occurance

Tags: javascript

I have to replace `""` (two quotes) with `"` (one quotes). I used:

```
string.replace(/""/g,'"')
```

but if it is having `""""` (four quotes) it is replacing with `"` (one quote) it is again replacing the `""` (two quotes) with `"` (one quote).

I need `""""` (four quotes) should be replaced with `""` (two quotes)

Comment: hmm no it doesn't `'""""'.replace(/""/g, '"')` gives `""`. Show us more code.

Comment: This seems to be working just fine: `'""""'.replace(/""/g,'"') -->
""""`

Comment: @thg435 agreed: http://jsfiddle.net/exrs7/

Comment: The code provided works as desired and the sentence beginning with "but if it is having..." is very hard to understand. -1 until it has been improved.

Comment: example: input: I like """"orange"""" and ""apple"".output:I like ""orange"" and "apple".

Comment: This code: `'I like """"orange"""" and ""apple""'.replace(/""/g,'"')` Does in fact return: `'I like ""orange"" and "apple"'`.
Your code works.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided in your question already does **exactly** what you say you want it to do:

```
'I like """"orange"""" and ""apple""'.replace(/""/g,'"');
// Returns:
'I like ""orange"" and "apple"'

'""'.replace(/""/g,'"');
// Returns:
'"'

'""""'.replace(/""/g,'"');
// Returns:
'""'
```

Unless you're missing some information in your question, there is nothing to solve.

for this reason, I believe the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace four quotes with two quotes, this does it:

```
var string = "\"\"\"\"";
string = string.replace("\"\"\"\"", "\"\"")
```

Comment: That hurts our eyes :) Why not simply `'""""'` and `'""'`?

Comment: What @PeterHerdenborg said, also, this doesn't replace `""` with `"`, only `""""` with `""`. As such, this doesn't answer the question.